# mkdir() not creating required directory when unziping

Tags: java, zip

I am trying to write method that unzip file keeping the original files and Folders structure, but, it seems that mkdir() is not creating required folders and because of this I keep getting : The system cannot find the path specified.
So, please any solution?
here is my code:

```
public static void unzip(File file) throws IOException{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.toString()));
        ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
        while(zipEntry != null){
            String fileName = zipEntry.getName();
                            System.out.println(file.toString().substring(0,file.toString().lastIndexOf("."))+"\\"+fileName);
            File newFile = new File(file.toString().substring(0,file.toString().lastIndexOf("."))+"/"+fileName);
            if(newFile.getParent()!=null){
               File f= new File(newFile.getParent())
               f.mkdir();


            }
            System.out.println(newFile.getParent());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            System.out.println(fileName);
            System.out.println(newFile.getName());
            System.out.println(newFile.getParent());
            System.out.print(file.getName().substring(0,file.getName().lastIndexOf("."))+"/" + fileName);


            int len;
            while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            zipEntry=zis.getNextEntry();
            fos.close();
        }
        zis.closeEntry();
        zis.close();

    }
```

Comment: try `mkdirs` instead of `mkdir`.

Comment: Are you sure that `f` contains the proper path?

Comment: mkdirs worked.. but may I ask why mkdirs worked but not mkdir?

Comment: mkdirs creates any missing intermediate folders in the path in addition to the folder you're asking it to create.

Comment: the `ZipInputStream` contains multiple directories and possible subdirectories to create, [File.mkdir()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir()) creates one directory, whereas [File.mkdirs()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) "Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories."